# Exception dose not working in execute immediate insert in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have some problem in execute immediate insert statement exception part.

I have a table `query_tb` that contains two columns (`DEPT`  and `SOURCE_VALUE`)

The column contains data in below

CLERK

```
select a.empno,a.ename,a.job,a.mgr,a.hiredate,b.deptno,b.dname,b.loc 
            from emp a,dept b where a.deptno=b.deptno and a.empno= '#V_GCIF#'
```

SALESMAN

```
select e.empno,e.ename,e.job,d.deptno,d.dname,d.loc from emp e,dept 
            d where e.deptno=d.deptno and e.empno= '#V_GCIF#'
```

MANAGER

```
select a.empno,a.ename,a.job,b.deptno,b.dname,b.loc from employee 
             a,department b where a.deptno=b.deptno and a.empno= '#V_GCIF#'
```

ADMIN

```
select a.empno,a.ename,a.job,b.deptno,b.dname,b.loc from employee 
            a,department b where a.deptno=b.deptno and a.empno= '#V_GCIF#'
```

If I pass the correct `empno` which is keep on the `emp` table it runs fine. But if I pass the incorrect `empno` (no data) then exception part not working.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE test_emp_sp(
    p_id IN VARCHAR2)
AS
  CURSOR rec
  IS
    SELECT dept,
      source_value
    FROM query_tb;
  v_query  VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

  FOR rec IN
  (SELECT dept,source_value FROM query_tb
  )
  LOOP
 IF rec.dept='CLERK' THEN
 v_query :=REPLACE(rec.source_value,'#V_GCIF#',p_id);

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO emp_tb (empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,deptno,dname,loc) ('||v_query|| ')';

 dbms_output.put_line(v_query||'    inserted');

ELSE

 v_query:=REPLACE(rec.source_value,'#V_GCIF#',p_id);

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO emp_tb (empno,ename,job,deptno,dname,loc) ('||v_query||')';

 dbms_output.put_line(v_query||'    inserting others');

  END IF;

  END LOOP;

 commit;

EXCEPTION

WHEN others THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('No data Found...');

END;
```

Comment: `when others then dbms_output...` with no `RAISE` is really bad programming practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are not running a `select` command, it is an `insert` command (`insert select`) which means that if the `select` won't return rows it just doesn't insert anything and no error is thrown for that. You should check whether the insert command has affected any rows. The way you do that in Oracle is checking the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` immediate after the execution, if it turns to be 0 then you do your job raising an exception. It would be something like:

```
DECLARE
   customException EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( customException, -20001 );

....
BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO emp_tb (empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,deptno,dname,loc) 
                       ('||v_query|| ')';
    IF (SQL%ROWCOUNT) = 0 then
       raise_application_error( -20001, 'This is a custom error' );
    end if;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN customException THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('No data Found...');  
END;
```

It's a long time without programming in Oracle PLSql So somethings there on the provided code may not compile but it is all there look into it in the internet and you will be good.

Comment: Now i am cleared if i want to add the bind variable some error occured in the following query                        
 v_query:=REPLACE(rec.source_value,'#V_GCIF#',':p_id');                                                                                                                            
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO emp_tb (empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,deptno,dname,loc) ('||v_query|| ')' using p_id;  --the error ora-01006 bind variable does not exist...

Comment: Add a dbms_output on v_query after the replace so we can see how it is the final sql string please.

Answer (score 0):

Exception does not work because there is no exception.
If SELECT returns NULL then 0 rows will be INSERT.
Example:

```
insert into t1(c1)
select 100 from dual where 1=0;
```

Result: 0 rows inserted.

Answer (score 0):

`insert into ... select from..` 
will not raise a no_data_found exception. It will just insert 0 records.

To test if you have inserted any records you can use SQL%ROWCOUNT after the insert statement.

```
execute immedate 'INSERT...;

if SQL%ROWCOUNT=0 
then
    dbms_output.put_line('no records inserted');
else
  ...
end if;
```

Also you might want to consider changing #V_GCIF# into something that can be used as a bind varaiable such as :P_ID.

You can skip the replace statement and change the execute immediate into something like:

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO ...'||v_query
using p_id;
```

This will bind the value of p_id to the :p_id in the statement.

Answer (score -1):

The very basic thing here is to capture the error appropriately so that you can able to track back. Here i have put loggers and EXCEPTION handlers jsut to check the error. Also i have put a RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR. Did some modifications too in the snipet. Hope it helps.

**PS: Have not checked for the syntax as i dont have workspace now with me.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE test_emp_sp(
    p_id IN VARCHAR2)
AS
--Not needed
--  CURSOR rec
--  IS
--    SELECT dept,
--      source_value
--    FROM query_tb;
--Not needed
  v_query VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  (SELECT dept,source_value FROM query_tb
  )
  LOOP
    IF rec.dept='CLERK' THEN
      v_query :=REPLACE(rec.source_value,'#V_GCIF#',p_id);
      BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO emp_tb (empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,deptno,dname,loc) ('||v_query|| ')';
      dbms_output.put_line(v_query||'    inserted');
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(' Error while inserting data in emp_tab for Clerk--> '||SQLCODE||'---'||SQLERRM);
      END;
    ELSE
      v_query:=REPLACE(rec.source_value,'#V_GCIF#',p_id);
      BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO emp_tb (empno,ename,job,deptno,dname,loc) ('||v_query||')';
      dbms_output.put_line(v_query||'    inserting others');
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(' Error while inserting data in emp_tab for other then clerk --> '||SQLCODE||'---'||SQLERRM);
      END;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Error occurred in the plsql block',TRUE);
END;
/
```

Comment: `when others then dbms_output...` without a `RAISE` is very poor programming practice. Your exception handlers will cause this code to ignore any and all exceptions.